# SAML SSO not working in Websphere Liberty

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml, websphere-liberty, login-page

I am attempting to implement SSO in Liberty for the first time. I have an application in Liberty that  I wish to be a service provider and using Azure as the Identity provider. For the moment I want to have SP initiate.

Following the 1st steps  in the link below:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=liberty-configuring-saml-web-browser-sso-in

I have put samlWeb-2.0
And

into the server.xml and I see SAML initiate.

Then I was able to get the SP metadata from the ibm/saml20/defaultSP/samlmetadata url.

I got the IDP metadata from Azure and installed in resources/security/idpMetadata.xml.

So when I access my application it goes to the login page above, but I get the message:

AADSTS750054: SAMLRequest or SAMLResponse must be present as query string parameters in HTTP request for SAML Redirect binding.

Which is true – there are  no query parameters. What am I missing here ? Why wouldn’t Liberty  be attempting to build an authorization request ?

Also, Azure wants me to install a certificate (either Base64 or Raw) and I assume it goes into security folder but shouldn’t I have to reference it ? I  note there are X509Certificate tags in the iDp metadata so I’m not sure how the cer files come into play.

I’d be grateful if anyone can  supply any guidance.

Comment: I would suggest you follow these steps here that the IBM Support team would use if you were asking them for help, click around on the different tabs to get to Liberty and troubleshooting
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/272965
Then review the data, if you find the solution great :-)  If you still need help let us know what you find when looking at your trace / logs etc.

Answer (score 0):

AADSTS750054 SAMLResponse must be present as query string parameters in HTTP request for SAML Redirect binding.

This error is due to incorrect idP login page URL is used for sso_1.sp.login.error.page property.

The SAML SSO you configured is idP-initiated SSO, and WebSphere does not support SAML Redirect binding. It only supports SAML POST binding. This document has more info about the error:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/277989

Search for AADSTS750054

If you have sso_1.sp.login.error.page pointing to the one defined in azure as login page, that url is requiring a SAMLRequest being sent.

Try changing sso_1.sp.login.error.page to the value from Azure console "Azure > Properties > access URL" instead and test after that.

Answer (score 0):

LIberty supports HTTP POST binding. Looks like your Azure is configured to support HTTP redirect binding. Could you modify your Azure setup to enable HTTP POST binding?